# qpc C++ timing issue

Tags: c++, timer

I am trying to use qpc to get high resolution timing in C++.

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
long x = (li.QuadPart)/PCFreq;
long y = 60*60*1000;


long h = x/y;
long m = (x-(h*y))/(y/60);
long s = (x-(h*y)-(m*(y/60)))/1000;
long mi = x-(h*y)-(m*(y/60))-(s*1000);
```

The li.quadpart in one machine 29251473450669. The li.quadpart is 74248079848 in another machine.
I am not sure why it is large in one machine and not so in another.

I am getting negative values for hours and seconds in the machine with the larger value. What is being done wrong here?

Comment: From the code you posted here, it looks like you are using `LARGE_INTEGER li` before you even initialize it. Try swapping the first two lines.

Comment: @Doug: that was a typo here. I did initialize properly.